# Hotel near Newark airport (EWR) for early morning use

Tags: hotels, new-york-city, sleeping, ewr, check-in

I am arriving at Newark airport (EWR) at 6 in the morning, and my next flight is late in the evening. I would like to get a few hours of sleep after I arrive (and don't want to pay too much for it, ideally under $80 USD).

- Is there a cheap hotel there with an option to check in *really*
  early, ideally around 7am ?
- I was also considering booking a room from the previous night, but
  then I have the reverse question - is there a cheap hotel near the
  airport with a really *late* checkout time, to give me enough time to
  sleep?

(By the way, I looked at https://www.hotelsbyday.com but the earliest checkin there is 9am)

Comment: What is your definition of a "few hours of sleep"?  A 9 am check-in and a "late evening flight" seems to me like it would allow 7 to 8 hours sleep (with a 5 - 6 pm return to the airport).

Comment: Ideally I don't want to wait for 3 hours after the flight before I can check in... The idea is to get some sleep right away (e.g. 7am-10 or 11am) and then have some time left to spend in NYC before the 8pm flight

Comment: Then it seems reserving from the night before at a hotel would work OK.  Many hotels with 11 am check outs are amenable about extending that to 12 noon so you could nap til 11 and have time for a shower before checking out to head into the big city

Comment: https://ca.hotels.com/ho539303/airport-hotel-inn-suites-newark-airport-elizabeth-united-states-of-america/ late check-out fee: USD 30.00

Answer (score 2):

Most hotels have a checkout time of 11am (or 12pm). If you're lucky, see if you can get a late checkout.

There's a Holiday Inn at newark that has a check in of 2pm and check out of 12pm, which looks like it fits within your parameters.

The only thing that I would suggest is let the hotel know ahead of time (if you book ahead of time) that you will be checking in the morning after the check in time.

So that is, if you book for April 1st, tell them that you're going to check in on April 2nd at 7am (or whatever time it is). Otherwise, the hotel will get confused if you don't check in before midnight and think that you're a no-show, and then charge you a fee, which happened to me.

Here's a link to the Holiday Inn that shows the check in/out times

http://www.ihg.com/holidayinn/hotels/us/en/newark/ewrhi/hoteldetail

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is any hotel around the airport with early check-in. Most of them have check-in between 12 and 2PM.

The only option I can recommend you to find someone from AirBnB, explain you situation and ask to check-in early. People there are more flexible and might work something out with your early arrival.

Good luck and welcome to NY (I mean NJ).

Comment: Many airports have a special hotel for travelers with an hourly payment and no unrestricted check-in times.