# How to search for a late checkout hotel?

Tags: online-resources, hotels, montreal, yul, accommodation-search-engines

This question comes up often, this time I am going to land at YUL at 00:33 and my next flight is at 16:55. Is there a hotel search engine which allows searching for late checkout? (Otherwise I'd need to ask for a "relatively cheap" airport hotel which allows for 2PM checkout and that'll be closed quick.)

Comment: Related / helpful?! http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/64362/32134 was left open so you might as well ask specifically for YUL, I would not close it.

Comment: This is a question that comes up often, I'd rather get an answer to this one.

Comment: Do you have status with any hotel chain or could you easily get one (afraid that would take it away from the more general case again, but might be helpful)?

Comment: http://www.rewardscanada.ca/cccompare-hotel.html I guess I could get Marriott Silver Elite or Best Western Gold easily.

Comment: https://www.between9and5.com/results.jsp finds one place for YUL from 10 to 5, would contact them directly to request a quote for your hours.

Comment: And that one is a midtown/downtown hotel, not airport at all. Waste of time to get there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47165/discussion-between-chx-and-mts).

Answer (score 4):

As far as I could find, there isn't any search engine that can specifically find late-checkout rooms. Some hotel chains offer it on their websites or list the late-checkout in their description, but you'd have to manually go through the list of hotels in the area. For example, you can search for ["Montreal" + "late check out"](https://www.google.cz/search?q=%20%22montreal%22%20%22late%20check%20out%22) in Google to find some options.

Otherwise several websites offer options for booking a "day room", but that usually means checking in around 9:00 and checking out by 17:00, which isn't exactly what you're looking for. Some random examples from Google:

[Hotelsbyday.com](https://www.hotelsbyday.com/)

[DayUse.com](https://www.dayuse.com/)

[Between9and5.com](https://www.between9and5.com/)

As suggested by @mts it might be possible to contact one of those hotels directly and arrange a different check-in/check-out time.

Comment: Like what was commented on the now deleted answer, can you please add a 'time of writing' and an 'as far as I know' to this, as you can not proof the negative.